# Getting earliest date by matching two columns, and returning array

Tags: amazon-redshift

I have a query I'm trying to write, but I cannot get the syntax quite right. From the table below, I have a set to dates with an `id`, and if the `id` does not have `parent_id`, and if the `parent_id` does not exist for an `id` it is `NULL`.

I'm trying to get an output of all the children of a parent that have the same date as the parent. As shown in the expected output below, `[D#P, Z#Z]` would be assigned to `A` because they have the same `date` and their `parent_id` is `A`, however `Q#L` would not be assigned to `A` because its date is not `1/1/2019`. Nothing is assigned to `B` or `D` because they have no children on their created dates.

I've found some posts on how to do this in Postgres, however because I'm using Redshift some of the operations don't work.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
|date   |id  |parent_id |
-------------------------
1/1/2019|A   |NULL
1/1/2019|B   |NULL
1/1/2019|C   |NULL
1/1/2019|D#P |A
1/1/2019|Z#Z |A
1/1/2019|K#H |C
1/2/2019|Q#L |A
1/3/2019|D   |NULL
1/4/2019|H#Q |C
```

Expected Output:

```
date     |id |children
-----------------------
1/1/2019 |A  |[D#P, Z#Z]
1/1/2019 |C  |[K#H]
```

Current Work:

```
SELECT
    first_value(case
            when parent_id
            then date
            end)
        over (
            partition by parent_id
            order by date
            rows between unbounded preceding and unbounded following)
        as first_date)
        id,
        list_agg(parent_id)
    FROM foo
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know why I am getting an error when using [`LISTAGG` aggregate function](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_LISTAGG.html), therefore I decided to use `SELECT DISTINCT` with [`LISTAGG` window function](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_WF_LISTAGG.html):

```
WITH input as (
  SELECT '1/1/2019' as date, 'A' as id, NULL as parent_id UNION ALL
  SELECT '1/1/2019', 'B', NULL                            UNION ALL
  SELECT '1/1/2019', 'C', NULL                            UNION ALL
  SELECT '1/1/2019', 'D#P', 'A'                           UNION ALL
  SELECT '1/1/2019', 'Z#Z', 'A'                           UNION ALL
  SELECT '1/1/2019', 'K#H', 'C'                           UNION ALL
  SELECT '1/2/2019', 'Q#L', 'A'                           UNION ALL
  SELECT '1/3/2019', 'D', NULL                            UNION ALL
  SELECT '1/4/2019', 'H#Q', 'C'
), parents as (
  SELECT *
  FROM input
  WHERE parent_id IS NULL
), children as (
  SELECT *
  FROM input
  WHERE parent_id IS NOT NULL
)

SELECT DISTINCT
  parents.date,
  parents.id,
  listagg(children.id, ',') WITHIN GROUP ( ORDER BY children.id )OVER (PARTITION BY parents.id, parents.date) as children
FROM parents JOIN children
                  ON parents.id = children.parent_id
                       AND parents.date = children.date
```

Outputs:

```
date        id  children
1/1/2019    A   D#P,Z#Z
1/1/2019    C   K#H
```

---

Solution with `GROUP BY` and an [`LISTAGG` aggregate function](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_LISTAGG.html), would be for me more *natural* of solving your problem:

```
WITH input as (
[...] 
SELECT 
  parents.date,
  parents.id,
  listagg(children.id, ',') WITHIN GROUP ( ORDER BY children.id )
FROM parents JOIN children
                  ON parents.id = children.parent_id
                       AND parents.date = children.date
group by parents.id, parents.date
```

Sadly it returns an error which I don't really understand:

> [XX000][500310] Amazon Invalid operation: One or more of the used functions must be applied on at least one user created tables. Examples of user table only functions are LISTAGG, MEDIAN, PERCENTILE_CONT, etc; java.lang.RuntimeException: com.amazon.support.exceptions.ErrorException: Amazon Invalid operation: One or more of the used functions must be applied on at least one user created tables. Examples of user table only functions are LISTAGG, MEDIAN, PERCENTILE_CONT, etc;

Comment: Huge! Thanks for answer this. I've never seen `WITHIN GROUP` so I'll take a look now. Cheers mate.

Comment: `WITHIN GROUP` just sorts children ids - you can also skip it if you don't care about the order.